# Manually insert a fifth element in linked linked list

Tags: c++, list, insert

I'm trying to insert an item in the fifth spot of a linked list. When I test the code it doesn't do anything. I've tried walking through this with a debugger but can't seem to figure it out.

```
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::insertNewFifthElement(const T& value) {
    int counter = 1;
    //New node to insert
    Node<T>* node = new Node<T>;
    //Value inserted into new node
    node->data = value;
    //Pointers
    Node<T>* temp = this->first;
    Node<T>* temp2 = node;

    while (counter != 4) {
        temp = temp->link;
        counter++;
    }
    if (counter == 4) {
        temp2->link = temp;
        temp->link = node;
    }

}
```

Comment: The right way to solve this problem is to add debug statements or step through the function with a debugger so that you can see what the program is doing. I find using the debugger is usually the quicker option. Debug statements only show what you ask to be shown and often the bug is a complete surprise.

Comment: Looks like having five elements in the list is guaranteed. This function would crash otherwise trying to dereference null pointer

Answer (score 0):

You set up a circular link, rather than inserting the node into the list.

```cpp
    if (counter == 4) {
        node->link = temp->link; //< note!
        temp->link = node;
    }
```